# Sankey: Display label outside of sankey and provide drag & drop functionality

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I need to show label outside of Sankey diagram but I am struggling to show outside. I tried using some properties like crop, overflow & align. Still, it is not working. I need to display label outside the graph both for left and right.

Here is my code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        showAxes: true,
        marginLeft: 150,
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        visible: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Cricket is the game', 'Sport Fest', 463 ],
            ['Football is the game', 'Sport Fest', 338 ],
            ['Basketball is the game', 'Sport Fest', 317],
            ['Baseball is the game', 'Sport Fest', 130 ],
        ],
        type: 'sankey',
    }],
     plotOptions: {
      sankey: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          useHTML: true,
          align: 'right',
          crop: false,
          overflow: "none",
        }
      }
    },
})
```

The second problem which I am facing is I need to provide drag and drop functionality but I don't understand for some reason drag & drop is not working. I have taken reference from this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/uknjrxvm/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        showAxes: true,
        marginLeft: 150,
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        visible: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Cricket is the game', 'Sport Fest', 463 ],
            ['Football is the game', 'Sport Fest', 338 ],
            ['Basketball is the game', 'Sport Fest', 317],
            ['Baseball is the game', 'Sport Fest', 130 ],
        ],
        dragDrop: {
                draggableX: true,
                draggableY: true,    
            },
        type: 'sankey',
    }],
     plotOptions: {
      sankey: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          useHTML: true,
          align: 'right',
          crop: false,
          overflow: "none",
        }
      }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display label outside the plot area, you can manipulate labels `align` property:

```
    events: {
        load() {
            Highcharts.each(this.series[0].nodeColumns[0], function(el) {
                el.dataLabel.attr({
                    align: 'right'
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6nsxzhLg/

Drag & drop functionality is not supported with these series type:

`['gauge', 'pie', 'sunburst', 'wordcloud',`**`'sankey'`**`, 'histogram', 'pareto', 'vector', 'windbarb', 'treemap', 'bellcurve', 'sma', 'map', 'mapline']`

Comment: One more thing I stated in the question that left label should come left side. Similarly, right label should come right. But sport fest is still coming on the chart it should come to right side

Comment: Hi Anonymous, please take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pef6s5cm/, it is possible to change the label position.